# SQLite update statement. Not updating all the time

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is for use in an android app. The first call works, not the second, and they are called in sequence. No errors. All strings are as should be. The first updates properly, but the second does not update either value.

```
///DOESN'T WORK
        mDbHelper.updateValue(SaveSlot, item, value1,value2,"S");



    public void updateValue(String saveslot, String item, String value1, String value2,String cat) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        if (value1 !=null){

        args.put(VALUE1, value1);
        if (value2 !=null){
            args.put(VALUE2, value2);
        }}
        else if (value2 !=null){
        args.put(VALUE2, value2);
        }
        mDb.update(DATABASE_PUSHERS_TABLE, args, SAVE_SLOT + "=" + saveslot +" AND " + ITEM +" = "+item+" AND category = "+cat, null);
        return ;
    }
```

found some error messages...

```
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43dc3e90 on pushers that has not been deactivated or closed
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
 INFO/dalvikvm(23920): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43da38c0 on pushers that has not been deactivated or closed


04-10 01:56:24.091: ERROR/Database(2983): Error updating value1=82 using UPDATE database SET value1=? WHERE save_slot=1 AND item = 98 AND category = S
```

Comment: What error message do you get? And is item defined as a String or a number in the table?

Comment: posted what errors i could find

Comment: is "item" defined earlier as a string? what is the schema of the database update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a single quote around the variables fixed it..

```
  mDb.update(DATABASE_PUSHERS_TABLE, args, SAVE_SLOT + " = '" + saveslot +"' AND " + ITEM +" = '"+item+"' AND category = '"+cat+"'", null);
```